# Angular universal SSR dynamic absolute base-herf path

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

Hey I have App based on this [starter kit](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/tree/5f0236c22e54004631304312aff36d15851930ad)

I deploy my app with the SSR feature from `server.ts`.

and the app is being served "dynamically" with Apache reverse proxy to localhost:4002 for multiple domains.

I.e
`domainA.com`
and `domainB.com` point to the same localhost:4002 with rev proxy.
All the domains use the same App instance
So far so good.

But now I've got a requirement for it to work under our partner reverse proxy which will look something like this `partner.com/app/` will reverse proxy to `partner.domainA.com`

Which causes a lot of problems when loading the JS.

Currently the base-href is set to `/` which works on our sites great.
but when a user goes to `partner.com/app` the browser tries to load all the JS assets from `partner.com/*.js` while the are only available on `partner.com/app/*.js` or `partner.domainA.com/*.js`.

My possible solution is to set `APP_BASE_HERF` from the server.ts when the request arrives.

But every thing I tried didn't seem to work.

I tried following this [guide](https://medium.com/@anandshende1994/setting-base-href-dynamically-in-angular-6-b7fe824848cf) but it didn't seem to work and it was loading the url from the `window`  object while I need to set it from the origin host which is available only from `req.headers.host`

in [server.ts](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/5f0236c22e54004631304312aff36d15851930ad/server.ts):

```
  res.render(
'../dist/index',
{
  req: req,
  res: res,
  // provers from server
  providers: [
    // for http and cookies
    {
      provide: REQUEST,
      useValue: req,
    },
    {
      provide: RESPONSE,
      useValue: res,
    },
    /// for cookie
    {
      provide: NgxRequest,
      useValue: req,
    },
    {
      provide: NgxResponce,
      useValue: res,
    },
    // for absolute path
    {
      provide: 'ORIGIN_URL',
      useValue: `${http}://${req.headers.host}`,
    },
  ],
},
```

is there a way to put the ORIGIN_URL in index.html base-herf?
What is the correct way to set the base-herf in that way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main.ts to :-

```
 window['base-href'] = window.location.pathname;
 if (env.production) {
    enableProdMode();
 }
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

in the above code, change url to where your base-href json is.

in appModule add this provider :-

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: window['base-href']
  }
  ]
```

Comment: All the domains use the same App instance
but then all the other sites wont work.
I.e `domainA.com` will try to load js from `domainA.com/app`
and only `partner.com/app` will work

Comment: the medium link you gave, is getting base-href from window.location.pathname. any problem in that?

Comment: do you have a json at your server from where you want to get base-href?

Comment: I use the json in the starter kit
https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/tree/5f0236c22e54004631304312aff36d15851930ad

Comment: i am asking do you want to get the base-href from some json on server?

Comment: Oh sry, no I want to get the base-href from the `ORIGIN_HOST` or `X-FOWRADED-FOR` in the request headers

Comment: your ui cannot read these headers before launching, but one thing can be done, to use  pathname approach for our benefit.

Comment: I see it, I will try it and update on how it goes thanks @Aakash!